# How do I force PrismaClient to return DateTime fields as Unix timestamps instead of a JavaScript date object?

Tags: typescript, datetime, types, prisma

Using the PrismaClient to interact with my database has DateTime fields return as JavaScript Date objects instead of Unix timestamp numbers. I need the dates returned as Unix timestamp numbers. I can also see in the database they are stored as Unix timestamp numbers. How do I stop PrismaClient from converting this unnecessarily?

My model:

```
model Settings {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  updatedAt DateTime   @updatedAt
}
```

The interaction:

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const mySettings = await prisma.settings.findFirst()
console.log(mySettings.updatedAt) // A javascript date object >:(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [middlewares](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) for versions before `4.7.0`, and since `4.7.0`, you can make use of [extensions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions), which quotes -

> Prisma Client extensions are Generally Available from versions 4.16.0 and later. They were introduced in Preview in version 4.7.0. Make sure you enable the clientExtensions Preview feature flag if you are running on a version earlier than 4.16.0.

### Using Middleware

Note that the type of the result will still remain of type `Date` with this method.

```ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// Does not give correct typings
prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
  const result = await next(params);
  if (typeof result === "object" && result !== null) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {
      if (value instanceof Date) {
        result[key as keyof typeof result] = Math.floor(
          Date.parse(value.toString()) / 1000
        );
      }
    }
    return result;
  } else {
    return result;
  }
});

async function main() {
  const res = await prisma.settings.findUnique({ where: { id: 1 } });
  console.dir(res, { depth: Infinity }); // { id: 1, updatedAt: 1691465195 }
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    await prisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

### Using Extension

With extensions, you've two options, either you modify by query (can be done for particular type of query -- for e.g., `findOne` -- or model, or a combination of both, note that you won't get correct type through this method) or by result (can be only for a specific model type, by adding a new property to the result of that model, that's computed at access time, note that this gives correct type).

Using an extension through **query modification** -

```ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// export default this instance for usage
const exPrisma = prisma.$extends({
  // If you wish to enforce the behavior for all the queries and models
  // Does not give correct typings
  query: {
    $allModels: {
      $allOperations({ args, model, operation, query }) {
        const result = query(args).then((res) => {
          if (typeof res === "object" && res !== null) {
            let modifiedRes = { ...res };
            for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(modifiedRes)) {
              if (value instanceof Date) {
                (modifiedRes[key as keyof typeof modifiedRes] as any) =
                  Math.floor(Date.parse(value.toString()) / 1000);
              }
            }
            return modifiedRes;
          } else {
            return res;
          }
        });
        return result;
      },
    },
  }
});

async function main() {
  const res = await exPrisma.settings.findUnique({ where: { id: 1 } });
  console.dir(res, { depth: Infinity });
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await exPrisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    await exPrisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Using an extension through **result modification** -

```ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();


// export default this instance for usage
const exPrisma = prisma.$extends({
  // Can only be done for specific models and gives correct typings
  result: {
    settings: {
      withUnixDate: {
        compute(data) {
          return {
            ...data,
            updatedAt: Math.floor(Date.parse(data.updatedAt.toString()) / 1000),
          };
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

async function main() {
  const res = await exPrisma.settings.findUnique({ where: { id: 1 } });
  console.dir(res?.withUnixDate, { depth: Infinity });
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await exPrisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    await exPrisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Make your pick per your requirements.

Comment: It's a shame we can't just get the raw database value without the unnecessary work on prisma, then having that work get undone on our side. 